# What's the easiest way to test a gateway?

Tags: linux, networking, gateway

I want to test a toy gateway I wrote. The testing will occur on Linux machines. I would like to do this in the easiest way possible, ideally writing no code and using existing utilities. This boils down to two questions:

1. Is there an existing utility that can send packets with simple stuff in them(like a string that I supply) to a host through a user-specified gateway, without reconfiguring Linux's network settings? If so, what syntax would I use for the utility?
2. Is there a simple utility I can run on the receiving end to verify that the correct packet was received? If so, what syntax would I use for the utility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the first, but I don't think it's that hard to modify your routing table:

`route add -host 1.2.3.4 gw 5.6.7.8`

(replace 1.2.3.4 by your target IP and 5.6.7.8 by the IP of your gateway).

For 2.:
On the target server type `netcat -l 1234` and on the client then type `netcat 1.2.3.4 1234`. (1234 is a "random" port number)(depending on your distribution netcat might be called simple "nc".) If a connection gets established you can just type data on the client or the server machine, press enter and see the data arriving on the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would probably be the [`nc(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc). Assuming your gateway IP is `192.168.1.1` and you are using TCP, then on the server, listening on port `8888`:

```
~$ nc -k -l 8888
```

On the client:

```
~$ nc 192.168.1.1 8888
  your input
  ...
  ^C
```

Comment: As far as I know a gateway allows to reach hosts in other networks, but your command is not displaying any host more than the gateway itself.

Comment: @Jaime, "gateway" is a very overloaded term in networking. The commands in my answer are for a beginner to test TCP connectivity between two ends - on the same network, through a gateway, over the Internet, etc.